# X-Content-Type-Options causes image to display as gibberish text [nginx]

Tags: nginx

I have setup to reverse proxy port 8086. Port 8086 is running a javascript that display random a image in webp format. If I try to visit the domain it displays the image as gibberish text. It works fine if I visit the ip address but not the domain.

I have out that `more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options : nosniff"` is causing the image to display as gibberish text. Is there a way to remove that setting for a specific site only? cause X-Content-Type-Options : nosniff is set to apply to all sites.

nginx conf

```
server {

    server_name sub.example.com www.sub.example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/sub.example.com.access.log ;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/sub.example.com.error.log;
    

    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8086/img;
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header X-Content-Type-Options "";
    }
}
```

How to remove X-Content-Type-Options : nosniff from specific site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in a "functional" way: always add the header with a value from map{}. Map $host $nosniff {myhost ''; default nosniff;}